# Keep background image CENTERED and UNSCALED regardless of browser window size

Tags: html, image, background, center, centering

I'm trying to edit the background so it stays centered. However everytime I resize the window to say a smaller size to test it out, the image shifts more and more to the left. I tried other codes but they wind up scaling down the background. If I view my page on another computer, the image is off center as well. :(

```
<style>
html, body {       
margin: 0px;    
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/zwbnaPk.jpg');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>
```

I'd like it to look centered like this regardless of the window size. Although it's slightly off in this photo, you get what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN5BR.jpg

Comment: You're code works for me

Comment: Works perfectly for me to. Try to clear cache and history (Ctrl + Shift + Del in Chrome). Or press Shift + F5. Btw, you got a sync-problem with your Gmail-account in Chrome.

Comment: What does my gmail account have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all...the black center part on your [background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ80e.jpg) is not on the center and second, you could accomplish same results with less CSS

```
html,
body {    
  background: #000 url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ80e.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the shortened version. But that doesn't fix my problem. I fixed the image on photoshop, however when the advertisement pops up on the left hand side of the page... it seems to shift my background. (http://vampirefreaks.com/cult/Upstate_and_Western_NY) When the advertisement doesn't appear, it centers just fine. So weird...